# Is it possible (yet) to use old laptop TFTs as extra monitors?

Tags: laptop, tft

I have several old laptops laying around which are in various states of brokenness.  It would be nice to be able to use the TFTs as extra (small) monitors on other computers, or to use them to hook up as test monitors when trying to diagnose other PCs.

Do laptops use a standard enough interface now that I'd be able to hook up something with the LVDS interface and make use of them?

(Note that the laptops which are working but no good to me have already gone to recycling/charity, so it's just ones which will only be any good as spares -- and if this really isn't possible then they'll get recycled too :)

Comment: I too have exactly the same situation. Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to purchase an LCD Controller to wire the laptop TFT into. Laptop LCD screens are disjoint from the necessary controller hardware that translates the standard VGA/DVI/etc signals to the arbitrary LCD signals.

So it's possible, your just going to have to spend money to do it. The other problem is finding a controller that is compatible with your harvested LCD screen.