# Can I use an old XP laptop as a second monitor?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is it possible (yet) to use old laptop TFTs as extra monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/1312/is-it-possible-yet-to-use-old-laptop-tfts-as-extra-monitors)
>   [Can I use my laptop as a second monitor for my desk computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-desk-computer)

I've an old 15" XP laptop, it's just lying around as it's useless in this day and age (How useless? Try a 400MHz CPU, 128MB RAM, and a 3GB HDD).

I just saw [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/51031/how-can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-2nd-monitor) about the exact same topic, but that thread is regarding Linux. I'm running Windows.

Comment: There's also this: http://superuser.com/questions/1312/is-it-possible-yet-to-use-old-laptop-tfts-as-extra-monitors :)

Comment: Actually, this one is even better: http://superuser.com/questions/15254/can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-desk-computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/) or [ZoneScreen](http://www.zoneos.com/index.htm) would be worth looking into.

Comment: I just bought MaxiVista, works fine with a wired network connection. With wireless, if you're on the edge of the range, each time it drops out, your main monitor will flicker as you change resolution, and the windows come back to the main monitor.

Comment: There is also [SpaceDesk](http://spacedesk.ph) for free.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using the freeware application [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/). Of course, your mileage may very, but it worked for me extending Windows XP desktops across two PCs.

Comment: I use Synergy, too. But it doesn't provide a way to use another PC as a secondary monitor. It provides keyboard and mouse of the "host" to the "guest" ;)